# Should arena rewards stack?

Tags: bladeslinger

Should awards in arena mode stack?   Because they don't.   For example, I'll start arena mode, and it might say "Gold 150, fragment 0, points 1000" - then, at the next post-boss screen (eg, just after level 3) it might say "Gold 0, fragment 1/3, poits 2000" ... It seems to me like these should add, so that the further I get, the greater the reward.   Instead, I need to choose - I can redeem and take the gold, or move on taking only the reward for a given set of 3 levels.

(It would also be nice if I could 're-roll' to get a better round-1 offer, but that one makes more sense as a deliberate choice.)

Thanks.

Comment: Also - this one doesn't seem like an appropriate SE question, but for any dev-team members who happen to read this (ahem) ... BS doesn't regain the screen properly.   If I switch to a new app, or just close the screen (power button), BS will resume, but with a blank screen.   So, I need to FC and restart it every time ... help?   (Humble Bundle version)

Comment: @brett-seyler lookin' at you ...

Comment: @Brett_Seyler @Brett\ Seyler where are you (sorry folks, trying to get the at-tag to work with a space)